# How to host a file directory on AWS website?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-applications, amazon-route53

I recently published my website via static HTML content in S3 and a .com domain I purchased through Route53.

One of the pages on my website is dedicated to my students. I would like them to be able to go to this page and download PDF files of their assignments, but I would like these PDF files to be organized.

Currently I have them organized on my desktop in directories (each word in CAPS is a folder/directory): MONTH --> WEEK --> WRITTEN ASSIGNMENT or QUIZ

**QUESTION:
What are some options for creating a file directory on my webpage? Since it is in AWS, what is the most cost effective way of doing this?**

Additional info: I can develop in python and java, I only have a handful of students (less than 10) accessing this content... let me know if you have any other questions.

Thank you,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Create a bucket for your students and set the permissions on the bucket to public (permission tab when you go to the bucket). When you click on each file in the bucket it will have an object url property you can send to anyone so they can get the file. If you have a few number of files you could just compile all the urls on your static page.

If you have a large number of files then there are some options programmatically...

Python:
You could create python script to get all the Urls. Use boto3 ([aws python sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)). Specifically, use the boto3 client to [list objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) in the s3 folder. You should get back a list of objects with the url's and those urls will have the folder/subfolder path within the url string. Output the list to a json file thats uploaded to your static html s3 bucket and write javascript to parse the json.

Purely Static Page w/ Javascript:
On your static page you could use the [aws sdk to get the list of objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html). You would have to setup an identity pool to provide to the js sdk. Once done you could get the list of objects back in the s3 bucket. Here's an example where an object list is retrieved from s3 to render images. It's images but it gives you an idea of how to get back data on the s3 bucket and create dynamic html with the object properties.

Comment: Thank you @Moh. Answer! I wrote a python script that generates presigned urls for each of the PDF files, writes them to a JSON file. Here is a mockup of what that JSON looks like once generated (instead of file.pdf, they are urls):  `{
  "bass": ["bass1.pdf", "bass2.pdf"],
  "drum": ["drum1.pdf", "drum2.pdf"],
  "guitar": ["guitar1.pdf", "guitar2.pdf"]
}`
Can you give me some guidance on next steps? I assume when people go to my webpage this script will run, create/overwrite the json file in my bucket, & I'll write some javascript that will help display these links on my webpage?